# Vue 3 router not going to fallback page cannot GET error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've found similar questions posted, but I cannot get the solutions to work. I am hosting a static SPA webpage with different router views. I am trying to get a fallback route to the home page, but getting the `CANNOT GET` error on browsers if I navigate to anything but the main URL. For example:

- [www.mywebpage.com](http://www.mywebpage.com) -> This works
- [www.mywebpage.com/services](http://www.mywebpage.com/services) -> This    won't work if entered into the
  browser

There is no problem navigating to a page from the main page. For example if I visit [www.mywebpage.com](http://www.mywebpage.com) and then click to navigate to [www.mywebpage.com/services](http://www.mywebpage.com/services). I understand this is because the browser is looking for a page that doesn't exist as the index.html is what needs to be landed on. But unsure how to fix this.

I've tried adding this route:

```
path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*', 
name: 'home', 
component: landing
```

I also have redirects as follows:

```
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: '/page-home'
  },
  {
    path: '/index.html',
    redirect: '/page-home'
  },
    path: '/page-home',
    name: 'Home',
    component: landing
  }
```

I'm creating the router with history modes:

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})
```

Comment: If this happens on production - you need to configure your web server to serve `index.html` instead of 404 errors. If you see `CANNOT GET` during development - than most probably it is something wrong with the Webpack-dev-server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to IVO GELOV's comment above. I didn't realize I would also need to set the web server fallback. I was able to have error pages be redirected to the index.html and resolve the issue.